# Enumerate column values in the where or join statement

Tags: sql, oracle

This is in Oracle SQL. I can't change the tables, only query what's already there.

I have a table of addresses with different types of addresses. Primary, Mailing, Location, EOB. I have a table of checks that were sent to different people.

```
Addresses
Group_ID             Type    
01                   Primary
02                   Location
02                   Primary
03                   Mailing
03                   EOB

Checks
AMT                  Group_ID
350.05               01
410.62               02
  1.05               03
```

I have a priority list ranking the address types as: Primary, Mailing, EOB, Location. I'm trying to figure out how to write a JOIN or a WHERE statement such that I only return the check with the highest address type listed for that group ID.

example:

```
AMT        Group_ID    Type
350.05     01          Primary
410.62     02          Primary
  1.05     03          Mailing
```

etc. Essentially enumerating the type of location and taking the MIN value. I can't add a rank column or anything like that unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function and a `CASE` statement to do this:

```
;
WITH cte AS (SELECT "AMT"
                   ,a."Group_ID"
                   ,b."Type"
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a."Group_ID" 
                                      ORDER BY CASE WHEN b."Type" = 'Primary' THEN 1
                                                       WHEN b."Type" = 'Mailing' THEN 2
                                                       WHEN b."Type" = 'Location' THEN 3
                                                       WHEN b."Type" = 'EOB' THEN 4
                                                       ELSE 5
                                                  END) AS RN

              FROM Checks a
              JOIN Addresses b
               ON a."Group_ID" = b."Group_ID"
               )
SELECT "AMT","Group_ID","Type"
FROM cte
WHERE "RN" = 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7629b/8/0)

You could also use a ranking function in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be like below; by getting the `MAX()` of `Type` in a inner query and joining with it.

```
select c.AMT,
tab."Group_ID",
tab.max_type
from checks c
join
(
select "Group_ID",
max("Type") as max_type
from Addresses
group by "Group_ID"
) tab on c."Group_ID" = tab."Group_ID"
```

Which will result in:

```
AMT     GROUP_ID    MAX_TYPE
350      1           Primary
411      2           Primary
1        3           Mailing
```

See a [DEMO Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7629b/15)

Comment: This only works by coincidence with this sample data.  Not a problem unless values change or the sample data isn't comprehensive.

Comment: That true can be. I went by problem statement and sample data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight variant on @GoatCO's solution.  I prefer it because it does the analytic function *before* the `join` rather than afterwards?

```
SELECT c.amt, c.Group_ID, a.Type
FROM checks c left join
     (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a.Group_ID
                                order by (case when a."Type" = 'Primary' then 1
                                               when a."Type" = 'Mailing' then 2
                                               when a."Type" = 'Location' then 3
                                               when a."Type" = 'EOB' then 4
                                               else 5
                                         )
                                ) as seqnum
      from addresses a
     ) a
     on c.Group_ID = a.Group_id and a.seqnum = 1;
```